# How to retrieve JsonArray from parse cloud to android?

Tags: javascript, java, android, json, parse-platform

I am trying to retrieve JsonArray from parse cloud to android, so far i have managed to send JsonArray from android to cloud like this :

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();           
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

        try {
            jsonObject.put("name", "first name");
            jsonObject.put("number", "111");
            jsonArray.put(jsonObject);

            JSONObject mainObj = new JSONObject();
            mainObj.put("contacts", jsonArray);
            params.put("all", mainObj);

            System.out.println(mainObj);
            System.out.println("-----------------------");
            System.out.println(jsonArray);
            System.out.println("-----------------------");
            System.out.println(params);

            ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("test", params, new FunctionCallback<HashMap<String, Object>>() {
                @Override
                public void done(HashMap<String, Object> object, ParseException e) {
                    System.out.println(object);
                    System.out.println(object.get("all").toString());
                }
            });


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

And the server part is this :

```
Parse.Cloud.define("test", function(request, response) {

  response.success(request.params);
});
```

But i keep getting null instead of the object and nullPointerException when i print :  `System.out.println(object.get("all").toString());`

> 01-10 20:46:27.526 28762-28762/com.example.swampsoftware.blbmonitor I/System.out: {"employees":[{"number":"111","name":"first name"}]}
>   01-10 20:46:27.526 28762-28762/com.example.swampsoftware.blbmonitor I/System.out: -----------------------
>   01-10 20:46:27.526 28762-28762/com.example.swampsoftware.blbmonitor I/System.out: [{"number":"111","name":"first name"}]
>   01-10 20:46:27.526 28762-28762/com.example.swampsoftware.blbmonitor I/System.out: -----------------------
>   01-10 20:46:27.526 28762-28762/com.example.swampsoftware.blbmonitor I/System.out: {movie=The Matrix, all={"employees":[{"number":"111","name":"first name"}]}}
>   01-10 20:46:27.576 28762-28762/com.example.swampsoftware.blbmonitor I/System.out:  =========== null
>   01-10 20:46:27.576 28762-28762/com.example.swampsoftware.blbmonitor D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
>   01-10 20:46:27.576 28762-28762/com.example.swampsoftware.blbmonitor W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40f8d300)
>   01-10 20:46:27.576 28762-28762/com.example.swampsoftware.blbmonitor E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                         java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                                             at com.example.swampsoftware.blbmonitor.MainActivity$1.done(MainActivity.java:117)
>                                                                                             at com.example.swampsoftware.blbmonitor.MainActivity$1.done(MainActivity.java:113)
>                                                                                             at com.parse.ParseTaskUtils$2$1.run(ParseTaskUtils.java:115)
>                                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
>                                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>                                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
>                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
>                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
>                                                                                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Thank you.

Comment: done() method is giving HashMap, you should consider that?

Comment: Yes I do, the problem is if the parse cloud is giving me a result at least it would tell me " cannot cast from - to - ", but it is giving me a null.

Comment: Firstly I think you should remove try catch here because Parse provides exception for their methods. Inside done() check if e==null else e.getLocalisedMessage();

Comment: Well, i tried to send json object {"name", "john"} and it worked perfectly inside the try catch, I believe that I am not succeeding in sending the JsonArray in the first place.

Comment: Yes, Parse has this thing of changing data type sent to client. Are logging in console in javascript?

Comment: no i don't having logging, i am writing the javascript code on a text editor

Comment: Change to Brackets or Sublime Text Editor